# How to remove `^I` character in Linux?

Tags: linux, sed

This looks a number of space(`20170628        ,`) but using `cat -A` it shows `^I` (`20170628^I,`).

I tried `sed -i '/s/^I//g' xxx` and `sed -i '/s/\^I//g' xxx`, but neither works.

How to delete this character ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a <kbd>tab</kbd> character, so you can use:

```
sed -i 's/\t//g/' fileToChange
```

for this.

Comment: Yes, that's the `ASCII` form of `tab`.  Thanks for your help.